# Running into 'Google Chrome cannot read and write to its data directory:' issue when running Karma on WSL2

Tags: angular, ubuntu, karma-jasmine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, symlink

I am having an issue running Karma on our Angular Project. Our project is set up on my Ubuntu WSL2, and after getting CHROME_BIN errors from Karma, I managed to set up a Symlink from my usr/bin/google-chrome to my chrome.exe on my Windows. Now it will open but I am running into this, and it stalls.

[image]

I am assuming that my Ubuntu user doesn't have the permissions that you usually need to run Google Chrome, but not sure how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: You might find a solution here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090298/karma-use-windows-chrome-from-wsl)